# Win10, after update - Programm, used to work, but only starts as Administrator now

Tags: windows-10

I am using a program 'Imagine' https://www.nyam.pe.kr/dev/imagine/ - a nice image viewer - since years. I used it with WinXP, Win7 and of course with Win10 as well.

But yesterday I was puzzled to find it not working (I normaly use my other PC with Linux, so maybe it's not working for some time).

So I tried to start it as Administrator - this works!. Also if I start imagine from Commandline with `imagine /about` the about dialog apears. I even downloaded (the portable zip version) and tried it freshly in a different folder... with no luck.

I tried to higher the users rights on the exe and the folder (german "Vollzugriff", full access) - with no luck.

I recocnized that starting the exe causes entries in the security log
[image]

But I have no clue what to do with that information.
My best guess is that imagine needs some of that "special permissions"

```
        SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
        SeTcbPrivilege
        SeSecurityPrivilege
        SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
        SeLoadDriverPrivilege
        SeBackupPrivilege
        SeRestorePrivilege
        SeDebugPrivilege
        SeAuditPrivilege
        SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege
        SeImpersonatePrivilege
        SeDelegateSessionUserImpersonatePrivilege
```

Which are greyed out (protected by group permission)

... so now my question: What do I need to do, to be able to start imagine as a normal user again?

[image]

Edit: Bonusquestion, is there a way to debug/log,... whats the started programm tries to access (much like when you start an windows programm from shell in wine...)

Answer (score 0):

> I used it with WinXP, Win7 and of course with Win10 as well.   .....
> my question: What do I need to do, to be able to start imagine as a
> normal user again?

The program is old enough (XP) that it may not be well behaved in Windows 10.  No surprise there.

You can try the following to see it it works:  Uninstall the program, restart the computer, run DISM / SFC, restart again, and install the program.

If that works, great.  If not, find a Windows 10 Image Viewer - Lots of these around.

DISM / SFC

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
```

Comment: a.) it worked with Win10 until recently... so I didn't get this "The program is old enough (XP) that it may not be well behaved in Windows 10." - I use a lot much older programms. b.) as it seems that Mircosoft has changed some Right-settings, I do not see any use of the suggested commands. How that would apply the missing rights? Note: started as admin, imagine works as it used to be. so all needed system libs, etc. seem to be availible. Its just the user has not the needed rights

Comment: Windows 10 keeps updating which is likely how all this changed for you. Older programs do not keep up with these changes.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the program, UNICODE version for 64-bit Windows, ZIP Version.
It's not an old version - the files date from April 2022.
I had no problem with this version.

Running `Imagine64.exe` for the first time got me this dialog :

[image]

I click "More info", then "Run anyway" and the program ran without problem.
The second time, it ran without any notification.

Comment: Of course I didn't use the same version for 15 years... and as I mentioned in my question I also downloaded the current availible version and that ist not working now (at my PC)

Comment: Sorry for implying you used an old program (I do have some such old ones on my computer), I deleted that paragraph. This works fine for me as detailed above - perhaps a problem with your security software? What happens when it's not working?

Comment: which versio of Windows you are running?

Comment: My version is 21H2.

Comment: Nothing happens... nothong opens... just a bit rotating of the mouse indicator. And there is no security SW other than defender... And I think I turned off all / most smart screening features, knowing that this stuff always causes trouble

Comment: Try it when booting in Safe mode, to disable all non-Microsoft installed products.

Comment: You need more modern programs if the old ones will not work properly. My answer lays all this out and Harry's answer was also informative.

Comment: @harrymc Tried Safemode, but its all the same - again, I think, its a rights issue e.g. as the programm might access something which now needs these special rights.

Comment: I find it hard to see why is this happening on your side, but not on mine. In which folder did you install the program?

Comment: @harrymc Users Download folder (some subfolder), c:\data\temp, c:\portapps\Graphics\imagine

Comment: Nothing wrong here that I can see. If you downloaded the same version as me : For 64-bit Windows, UNICODE Version, ZIP Version, then there is no explanation except some app on your computer., so try it when booting from Safe mode.